# wxMathPlot with x-axis in milliseconds?

Tags: wxmathplot

I'm working with Sensor HID device and wxWidgets host application respectively.

Process Flow:

1.Sensor sends float value with time-stamp(in milliseconds) for every few milliseconds to seconds.

2.Host application reads the data and represents it in a chart (x-axis as time and y-axis as float value).

I'm using the mpFXYVector and mpScaleX with mpX_TIME.

If the time-stamp is in milliseconds, x-axis time ticks are not coming properly.

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Regards,

Rajan.M

Answer (score 0):

The issue is I've passed the time value in milliseconds directly instead of converting it to seconds!

E.g. 45678 milliseconds to 45.678 seconds